# C# - Streaming video from IP Camera with overlay to Facebook Live

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, rtmp, ip-camera, facebook-live-api

I am currently working on a project where I am trying to have a C# application connect to multiple IP Cameras where I will add an overlay and continue to forward that stream to an RTMP server like Facebook Live. I am currently using the Ozeki Camera SDK to work with my IP Cameras but I have looked into using AForge as well.

I have everything set up to stream and overlay but I am having some trouble understanding how I can convert video and audio to be stream-able to the Facebook RTMP server. It seems I have to have an encoder for the video but after Googling, I am coming up short with methods of how to achieve this. I am hoping that someone has some experience in this field can give me a hand.

Thanks in advance.